# how to design the return type of trait method?

Tags: rust, types, traits

I start to implement an utility for SKU that a product takes multiple units. The basic logic is:

- Convert the list of amounts into a single amount with base unit.
- Split a single amount with base unit into a list of human readable amounts.

### Example

```rust
let five = "5kg".parse::<Amount>()?;
let two = "2g".parse::<Amount>()?;

let sum = five + two;
let result = sum * 3;

let result = Weight.reduce(result)?;
assert_eq!(result, Amount::new(15006, Weight.base_unit()));

let result = Weight.split(result)?.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
assert_eq!(result, [Amount::new(15, kg()), Amount::new(6, g())]);
```

### Design

The code design as below:

```rust
use std::ops::{Add, Mul};

trait Exchanger {
    type Err;

    fn rate(&self, unit: &Unit) -> Result<u32, Self::Err>;

    fn reduce<E>(&self, expr: E) -> Result<Amount, Self::Err>
    where
        for<'a> E: Reduce<&'a Self>,
        Self: Sized,
    {
        expr.reduce(self)
    }

    fn split<E>(&self, expr: E) -> Result<Split, Self::Err>
    where
        for<'a> E: Reduce<&'a Self>,
        Self: Sized,
    {
        let base = expr.reduce(self)?;
        todo!()
    }
}

impl<T: Exchanger> Exchanger for &T {
    type Err = T::Err;

    fn rate(&self, unit: &Unit) -> Result<u32, Self::Err> {
        (**self).rate(unit)
    }
}

trait Reduce<E: Exchanger> {
    fn reduce(self, e: E) -> Result<Amount, E::Err>;
}

trait Expression<E: Exchanger, Rhs, T>: Reduce<E> + Add<Rhs> + Mul<T> {}

// impls Expression<E, Rhs, T>
struct Amount(u32, Unit);

struct Unit(String);

// impls Expression<E, Rhs, T>
struct Sum<L, R>(L, R);

// impls Expression<E, Rhs, T>
struct Split(Vec<Amount>);
```

### Problems

The design above has problems and isn't elegant, I think.

1. The first one is I need
   to define an additional struct `Split`, since the return type of `Exchanger::split` maybe: `Amount` or `Sum`, but this is fine in [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) just introduce an interface like `Expression`. I tried to use `Box<dyn Expression>` but it takes generic parameters and I can't feed them at compile-time.
2. I need to re-implement `Expression` for the new type `Split`.
3. Whenever I add a new type `T` that implements `Expression`, I must also implement `Add<T>` for all types that has implemented `Expression`,
   such **combination is explosive**, e.g:

   ```rust
   struct NewType;
   impl Add<NewType> for NewType {}
   impl Add<Amount> for NewType {}
   impl Add<Sum> for NewType {}
   impl Add<Split> for NewType {}

   impl Add<NewType> for Amount {}
   impl Add<NewType> for Sum {}
   impl Add<NewType> for Split {}

   // impl all reference types, and so on.
   impl Add<NewType> for &Amount {}
   ```
4. I also need to implements all traits just for reference type, e.g:

   ```rust
   trait Trait {}

   impl <T: Trait> Trait for &T{}
   ```

Can you tell me a better way to achieve the current design?
You can also refer to the [github repository](https://github.com/holi-java/amount/tree/5efdbdadf8aba772b1d532fd0cbff8a22f364153) to see the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to do what you describe as base logic, I would do something like this:

```rust
use std::{error::Error, fmt::Display, num::ParseIntError, ops::Add, str::FromStr};

/// A type representing all units of a certain quantity (e.g kg, g, t, etc.)
pub trait Unit: Sized {
    /// The base unit. All others units are a multiples of it.
    fn base() -> Self;

    /// The magnitude of this unit with respect to the base unit. The base unit itself hasµ
    /// magnitude 1.
    ///
    /// For example, if the base unit is the gram, then the kilogram would have a magnitude of
    /// 1000.
    fn magnitude(&self) -> u32;

    /// All units of this quantity, in decreasing order of magnitude.
    ///
    /// For example: [t, kg, g]
    fn sorted_units() -> Vec<Self>;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Quantity<U> {
    pub amount: u32,
    pub unit: U,
}

impl<U> Quantity<U> {
    pub fn new(amount: u32, unit: U) -> Self {
        Self { amount, unit }
    }
}

impl<U: Unit> Quantity<U> {
    /// Splits this quantity into different units
    pub fn split(&self) -> Vec<Self> {
        let mut amount = self.amount * self.unit.magnitude();
        let mut split = vec![];
        for unit in U::sorted_units() {
            let mag = unit.magnitude();
            let whole = amount / mag;
            if whole != 0 {
                split.push(Self {
                    amount: whole,
                    unit,
                })
            }
            amount -= whole * mag;
        }
        split
    }
}

impl<U: Unit> Add for Quantity<U> {
    type Output = Self;
    /// Output always in terms of the "base unit"
    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            amount: self.amount * self.unit.magnitude() + rhs.amount * rhs.unit.magnitude(),
            unit: U::base(),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum ParseQuantityError<UErr> {
    InvalidAmount(ParseIntError),
    InvalidUnit(UErr),
}

impl<U: FromStr> FromStr for Quantity<U> {
    type Err = ParseQuantityError<<U as FromStr>::Err>;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let first_non_digit_idx = s
            .char_indices()
            .find(|(_, c)| !c.is_ascii_digit())
            .map(|(idx, _)| idx)
            .unwrap_or(s.len());

        let amount = s[..first_non_digit_idx]
            .parse::<u32>()
            .map_err(ParseQuantityError::InvalidAmount)?;

        let unit = s[first_non_digit_idx..]
            .parse::<U>()
            .map_err(ParseQuantityError::InvalidUnit)?;

        Ok(Self { amount, unit })
    }
}

impl<UErr: Display> Display for ParseQuantityError<UErr> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::InvalidAmount(err) => write!(f, "failed to parse `Quantity` amount: {err}"),
            Self::InvalidUnit(err) => write!(f, "failed to parse `Quantity` unit: {err}"),
        }
    }
}

impl<UErr: Error> Error for ParseQuantityError<UErr> {}
```

This design has multiple advantages:

- It's pretty small
- Every dimension can be a separate type (most likely an enum), which makes weird operations like adding kilograms and liters impossible
- Creating a new unit is only a matter of implementing the `Unit` and possibly the standard `FromStr` trait

For example, to represent mass with multiple units:

```rust
use std::{error::Error, fmt::Display, str::FromStr};

pub type Mass = Quantity<MassUnit>;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum MassUnit {
    G,
    Kg,
}

impl Unit for MassUnit {
    fn base() -> Self {
        Self::G
    }

    fn magnitude(&self) -> u32 {
        match self {
            Self::G => 1,
            Self::Kg => 1000,
        }
    }

    fn sorted_units() -> Vec<Self> {
        vec![Self::Kg, Self::G]
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct InvalidMassUnit;

impl FromStr for MassUnit {
    type Err = InvalidMassUnit;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match s {
            "g" => Ok(Self::G),
            "kg" => Ok(Self::Kg),
            _ => Err(InvalidMassUnit),
        }
    }
}

impl Display for InvalidMassUnit {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "invalid mass unit")
    }
}

impl Error for InvalidMassUnit {}
```

Which can be used like this:

```rust
let five_kg = "5kg".parse::<Mass>()?;
let two_g = "2g".parse::<Mass>()?;

let sum = five_kg + two_g;
assert_eq!(sum, Mass::new(5002, MassUnit::base()));

let split = sum.split();
assert_eq!(
    split,
    [Mass::new(5, MassUnit::Kg), Mass::new(2, MassUnit::G)]
);
```

I've taken the liberty to remove the `Sum` type, but if you think you need it as an extra layer in your computation, adding it shouldn't be too hard.

---

I'm also assuming you really need to be able to represent similar quantities with different units; otherwise, the problem almost disappears, and you can replace every `Quantity<U>` type with a [newtype](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html), like so:

```rust
pub struct Grams(u32);

pub struct Millimeters(u32);
```

You'd maybe want to keep `Quantity<U>` for the return value of `split`, if that can't just live in the `Display` impl.

### Edit

If you can't necessarily know the units at compile-time, this is how I would do things.

```rust
use std::{error::Error, fmt::Display, num::ParseIntError, str::FromStr};

/// A type holding information about a certain type that can represent multiple units.
pub trait Exchanger<U> {
    /// The base unit. All others units are a multiples of it.
    fn base_unit(&self) -> U;

    /// The magnitude of this unit with respect to the base unit. The base unit itself hasµ
    /// magnitude 1.
    ///
    /// For example, if the base unit is the gram, then the kilogram would have a magnitude of
    /// 1000.
    fn magnitude(&self, unit: &U) -> u32;

    /// All units of this quantity, in decreasing order of magnitude.
    ///
    /// For example: [t, kg, g]
    fn sorted_units(&self) -> Vec<U>;

    type ParseUnitError;

    fn parse_unit(&self, s: &str) -> Result<U, Self::ParseUnitError>;

    fn parse_quantity(
        &self,
        s: &str,
    ) -> Result<Quantity<U>, ParseQuantityError<Self::ParseUnitError>> {
        let first_non_digit_idx = s
            .char_indices()
            .find(|(_, c)| !c.is_ascii_digit())
            .map(|(idx, _)| idx)
            .unwrap_or(s.len());

        let amount = s[..first_non_digit_idx]
            .parse::<u32>()
            .map_err(ParseQuantityError::InvalidAmount)?;

        let unit = self
            .parse_unit(&s[first_non_digit_idx..])
            .map_err(ParseQuantityError::InvalidUnit)?;

        Ok(Quantity { amount, unit })
    }

    fn add(&self, lhs: Quantity<U>, rhs: Quantity<U>) -> Quantity<U> {
        Quantity {
            amount: lhs.amount * self.magnitude(&lhs.unit) + rhs.amount * self.magnitude(&rhs.unit),
            unit: self.base_unit(),
        }
    }

    /// Splits this quantity into different units
    fn split(&self, quantity: Quantity<U>) -> Vec<Quantity<U>> {
        let mut amount = quantity.amount * self.magnitude(&quantity.unit);
        let mut split = vec![];
        for unit in self.sorted_units() {
            let mag = self.magnitude(&unit);
            let whole = amount / mag;
            if whole != 0 {
                split.push(Quantity {
                    amount: whole,
                    unit,
                })
            }
            amount -= whole * mag;
        }
        split
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Quantity<U> {
    pub amount: u32,
    pub unit: U,
}

impl<U> Quantity<U> {
    pub fn new(amount: u32, unit: U) -> Self {
        Self { amount, unit }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum ParseQuantityError<UErr> {
    InvalidAmount(ParseIntError),
    InvalidUnit(UErr),
}

impl<U: FromStr> FromStr for Quantity<U> {
    type Err = ParseQuantityError<<U as FromStr>::Err>;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let first_non_digit_idx = s
            .char_indices()
            .find(|(_, c)| !c.is_ascii_digit())
            .map(|(idx, _)| idx)
            .unwrap_or(s.len());

        let amount = s[..first_non_digit_idx]
            .parse::<u32>()
            .map_err(ParseQuantityError::InvalidAmount)?;

        let unit = s[first_non_digit_idx..]
            .parse::<U>()
            .map_err(ParseQuantityError::InvalidUnit)?;

        Ok(Self { amount, unit })
    }
}

impl<UErr: Display> Display for ParseQuantityError<UErr> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::InvalidAmount(err) => write!(f, "failed to parse `Quantity` amount: {err}"),
            Self::InvalidUnit(err) => write!(f, "failed to parse `Quantity` unit: {err}"),
        }
    }
}

impl<UErr: Error> Error for ParseQuantityError<UErr> {}
```

For example:

```rust
use std::{error::Error, fmt::Display};

use crate::Exchanger;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct FooUnit {
    index: usize,
}

pub struct FooExchanger {
    units: Vec<(String, u32)>,
}

impl FooExchanger {
    pub fn new(base: String, mut units: Vec<(String, u32)>) -> Self {
        units.push((base, 1));
        units.sort_unstable_by_key(|(_, mag)| u32::MAX - mag);
        Self { units }
    }
}

impl Exchanger<FooUnit> for FooExchanger {
    fn base_unit(&self) -> FooUnit {
        FooUnit {
            index: self.units.len() - 1,
        }
    }

    fn magnitude(&self, unit: &FooUnit) -> u32 {
        self.units[unit.index].1
    }

    fn sorted_units(&self) -> Vec<FooUnit> {
        (0..self.units.len())
            .map(|index| FooUnit { index })
            .collect()
    }

    type ParseUnitError = InvalidFooUnit;
    fn parse_unit(&self, s: &str) -> Result<FooUnit, Self::ParseUnitError> {
        let index = self
            .units
            .iter()
            .position(|(name, _)| name == s)
            .ok_or(InvalidFooUnit)?;
        Ok(FooUnit { index })
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct InvalidFooUnit;

impl Display for InvalidFooUnit {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "invalid unit")
    }
}

impl Error for InvalidFooUnit {}
```

Which can be used like this:

```rust
let exchanger = FooExchanger::new("g".to_string(), vec![("kg".to_string(), 1000)]);

let five_kg = exchanger.parse_quantity("5kg").unwrap();
let two_g = exchanger.parse_quantity("2g").unwrap();

let sum = exchanger.add(five_kg, two_g);
assert_eq!(sum, Quantity::new(5002, exchanger.base_unit()));

let split = exchanger.split(sum);
assert_eq!(
    split,
    [
        Quantity::new(5, exchanger.parse_unit("kg").unwrap()),
        Quantity::new(2, exchanger.parse_unit("g").unwrap())
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks. The design is cool if the number of units is fixed. But I need both customized units and standard units for SKU, sir.

Comment: If by "customized", you mean that you can't know all units at compile-time, I see your problem. I would move the logic of the `Unit` trait to a new trait similar to your `Exchanger`; all methods would then take a `&self` parameter. Implementors would keep track of which units a certain type `U` can represent. I would also move the addition logic to this trait and ditch `Sum`, `Expression` and `Reduce` which (correct me if I'm wrong here) you seem to only need to be able to use the `+` operator. If you don't strictly need it, you'd write something like `exchanger.add(quantity1, quantity2)`.

Comment: Great! Could you write the `Exchanger` trait with `reduce` and `split`  methods in answer ? Yours is the simplified design, thanks.

Comment: I like the `Unit` design, it just indexing `String` unit only. Thanks!